# overriding virtual function with a non-virtual function

Tags: c++

I have the header file "testcode.h"

```
#ifndef TESTCODE_H
#define TESTCODE_H

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    virtual void Foo();

public:
    int mPublic;

protected:
    int mProtected;

private:
    int mPrivate;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    void Foo();
};

#endif // TESTCODE_H
```

and a source file

```
#include "TestCode.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A* b = new B();
    b->Foo();

    b->mPublic = 0;
    b->mProtected = 0;
    b->mPrivate = 0;

    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, i would like to know that when I am calling "b->Foo", the Foo function of the class B is called instead of class A. However, the Foo function of class B is not declared as virtual. Can anyone elaborate on this ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once a function is declared virtual in a base class, it doesn't matter if the `virtual` keyword is used in the derived class's function. It will always be virtual in derived classes (whether or not it is so declared).

From the C++11 standard, 10.3.2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5),
>   cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is
>   declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so
>   declared) and it overrides Base::vf. ...

Comment: so suppose for a class C extending class B, the same rule will be applicable ?? Will it's "Foo" function also be virtual by default ??

Comment: Yes, the "derived directly or indirectly from Base" means you can have several levels of derivation. Once it's virtual in a base class, then every derived class function matching the name, parameters, etc. with be virtual.

Answer (score 3):

`B::Foo` doesn't need to be declared as virtual--the fact that `A::Foo` is virtual and B derives from A means it's virtual (and overridden). Check out the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y01k918%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the virtual functions for more info.